# cURL POST is not redirecting

Tags: php, curl

This cURL post is not redirecting to the url, instead its printing all that page within the same php page where this code resides one.

```
$cha = curl_init("https://checkout.dineromail.com/CheckOut");
curl_setopt($cha, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($cha, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
curl_exec($cha);
curl_close($cha);
```

I basically posts the values on the page to that checkout page, but right now its not redirecting like a normal html form, anyone know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

this example has worked for me in the past [cURL](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm), but i'm not sure why you don't use normal post, unless that is a webservice that collects the fields you're posting.  you should redirect on the response code options that's returned from cURL, just put this before your curl close:

```
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

hopefully, you're returned a 200, or 204 status code after posting. good luck and i hope it helps.

Comment: no, it doesnt work. Any other solution? i added that line before the curl_close and get the same result

Answer (score 0):

A cURL post doesn't actually send you to the page, it only posts the data to the page and returns what the page displayed.
The only way to achieve what you're trying to do is with an HTML form.

Another way you could achieve what you're trying to do is with PHP sessions. Here are your two example pages:

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['order_id'] = 'sample value';
$_SESSION['other_value'] = 'another sample value';
header('Location: checkout.php');
?>
```

checkout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['order_id'];
echo $_SESSION['other_value'];
?>
```

Hope this helps!